# C structure and C++ structure

Tags: c++, c

Could anybody please tell me what is the main difference 
between C & C++ structures.

Comment: C structures cannot contain methods whereas C++ structures can :)

Comment: C structures are basically used to group the data.

Comment: C++ structures support inheritance. :)

Comment: C++ structures support private members

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In C++ `struct` and `class` are the exact same thing, except for that struct defaults to `public` visibility and class defaults to `private` visiblity.

In C, struct names are in their own namespace, so if you have `struct Foo {};`, you need to write `struct Foo foo;` to create a variable of that type, while in C++ you can write just `Foo foo;`, albeit the C style is also permitted. C programmers usually use `typedef struct {} Foo;` to allow the C++ syntax for variable definitions.

The C programming language also does not support visibility restrictions, member functions or inheritance.

Comment: In C++ struct names are also in their own name space. The difference is that when searching for an identifier the compiler will first look in the general name space, and if not found will also check the user-defined-classes name space. In c++ his is correct: `struct x {}; void x() {}` while this is not `typedef struct x {} x; void x() {}`, as the global identifier space already has an `x` (typedef) the declaration of the function will collide (BTW, in the first example, to create a variable you need to write `struct x var` so that the identifier is only searched for as a user defined type).

Answer (score 12):

In C++, structures behave like classes, allowing methods, constructors, destructors etc...

The main difference between classes and C++ structures is that everything inside structures is *public* by default, while everything inside classes is *private* by default. (ie: nothing outside can access them directly)

Comment: According to my CS prof, another difference between structs and classes is "you can't fail a struct"

Answer (score 7):

There are several differences in C and C++ structure

1. In C we define struct keyword is necessary to create the structure type value while in C++ it is not necessary.
2. In C there is no function inside the structure while in C++ we can define function that can access the data members of structure directly( Function is names as method in C++ )
3. There is no concept of access modifier inside the structure in C while in C++ we can find the access modifier (eg. private and public ). By default all are public.
4. Structure in C can not have static members while in C++ structure can have static members.
5. Size of empty structure is constraint violation in C, but it is always 1 in C++.
6. We can have both pointers and references to struct in C++, but only pointers to structs are allowed. (References aren't feature of C language)

Comment: In C we have to write struct keyword when we declare a variable of the structure type.                                                                                    
 Example:  Struct ABC var1, var2;                                                                                 While C++ approaches to minimize the gap between derived data type and built-in data type.  So like we define int or char, here we can declare the structure variable directly as: Example: ABC var1, var2;

Comment: Ah ok yes I understand you meant, you have to type struct also to declare new variables

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answers above, remember that C++ structures support inheritance and so can contain pointers to vtables. This can make a big difference when serializing and deserializing these structures across processes. Templates are supported too.

Comment: Rather than mentioning vtables (which are not in the C++ language specification) you should mention `virtual` methods.

Comment: The best process for serializing and deserializing structures is to have functionality that accesses the data fields (members) individually.  Applies to both C and C++ languages.  One primary reason is that the compiler is allowed to add padding between members (applies to both languages).

Comment: In C, padding is only a matter of a few unused bytes when the data in serialized and deserialized in it's binary representation. With C++, it can create problems when using objects of classes with virtual functions.

Answer (score 3):

C structs is more akin to a definition of a composite data structure

C++ structs can be thought of as a class but scope of all member variables are defaulted to public.

Answer (score 3):

C : we can't define function inside the structure in c.

C++ : We can define function inside the structure in c++.