# Structs and Cuda C

Tags: cuda

I don't recall being able to add constructors and overloaded operators to structs in plain C.  In a book I'm reading it uses both in an example of CUDA C.

If there are any differences between structs in C and CUDA C, what would be a general explanation of them?  In the book they use C++ style structs in CUDA C.

Comment: CUDA C is much closer to C++ than C. Just read the examples as if they were C++.

Comment: The question [C structure and C++ structure ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242696/c-structure-and-c-structure) should provide your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) C struct can only contain data member, but CUDA C is more like the C++ style class which can contain functions etc.

2) Only major difference between CUDA struct and CUDA class is that in the former all members are public by default.

Answer (score 2):

CUDA C is really CUDA C++ and relies on a C++ compiler.

From experience `nvcc` has trouble compiling actual C code (for the same reason a C++ compiler might).

There once was a `--host-compilation` option that switched the compiler from `C` to `C++` but it never worked. (see [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/508479/cuda-programming-and-performance/nvcc-forces-c-compilation-of-cu-files/#entry1340190))