# incomplete definition of type struct

Tags: c, struct

I am implementing Priority Queue of `int` in C. I have a `struct Node` in my header

```
typedef struct NodeTag {
  int priority;
  int value;
  struct Node *next;
}Node;
```

Now in my C file I am trying to add a new element while traversing the queue and comparing the priorities values of each element inside with the new one. So I try to do this

```
Node *prev = head;
while(prev->next && prev->next->priority >= priority){
   prev=prev->next;
}
temp->next=prev->next;
prev->next=temp;
```

But I get a compiler error saying:

```
incomplete definition of type 'struct Node'
```

On my while condition. How to access the property of priority of the next node of `prev`?

Comment: This is a common mistake, especially in beginner's code here on SO.  The difficulty is finding a good question to make this one a duplicate of.

Comment: Can take a look about "struct" in C language. try use struct Node *prev = head
[browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242696/c-structure-and-c-structure)

Comment: actually if you ever try to read c std you will know why `struct` in a type is for

Comment: And another very relevant Q&A is [typedef a structure containing a pointer to the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474774).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct NodeTag {
  int priority;
  int value;
  struct Node *next; /*this should be struct NodeTag, 
                      at this point Node is still not yet typed*/

  }Node; /*now it is*/
```

to get over this you should do this:

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node{
     int priority;
     int value;
     Node *next; 
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have mixed up which is the type name, and which is the struct name.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions).

Either declare the `next` field as `Node *` or as `struct NodeTag *`.

Here's a compiling snippet:

```
typedef struct NodeTag Node;
struct NodeTag {
  int priority;
  int value;
  Node *next;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! When I declare it as Node * I get an error saying "must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'Node'"

Comment: @Aida updated answer. I had to split the typedef off from the struct, otherwise it doesn't know type Node yet for the `next` field.

Comment: @AidaZhumabekova: There are multiple ways to fix it, including (1) `typedef struct Node {
  int priority;
  int value;
  struct Node *next;
} Node;` and (2) `typedef struct Node Node; struct Node {
  int priority;
  int value;
  Node *next;
};` and (3) `typedef struct NodeTag {
  int priority;
  int value;
  struct NodeTag *next;
} Node;` — any of which will work just fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm afraid that my suggestion *"or as `struct NodeTag`"* in the answer has the same problem as (3): `prev=prev->next` would assign a `struct NodeTag` to type `Node`, which the compiler probably won't like...

Comment: Once the semicolon at the end of (3) is reached, `Node` is an alias for `struct NodeTag` and there is no problem.  The difficulty is when you're in the middle, as in (1), where the is no type `Node` at the point when `next` is defined, so you have to use `struct Node` in that example.  (2) gets around the problem by saying `Node` is an alias for `struct Node`, and then defining what a `struct Node` is.  The structure body can use just `Node` (the typedef name) as shown, or `struct Node`; the result is the same.